# Gvim - folding is not working

Tags: ubuntu, vim

i have a - probably - simple problem with gVim under Ubuntu. I can't use folding in my files. I'm using all the folding releated commands like zi, zm, zr, etc. but none of it seems to work. I'm not even getting any errors after using them.

Is there any option i should turn on before i can start using folding (if that's important - folding is also not working under regular, non graphical Vim) ? My gVim version is 7.2.330

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm editing PHP and HTML files. Folding method is set to manual but none of the metods seems to change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [`manual`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-manual) folding, you have to create the folds before you can use them.

Select an area you want to fold in visual mode and then type [`zf`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#zf) to create the fold. Consulting [`:help fold-commands`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-commands) gives you more info on that.

The disadvantage of [`manual`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-manual) is, that your created folds are lost after you close the file. To have persistent folds, try setting the [`foldmethod`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27foldmethod%27) to [`syntax`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-syntax) which creates folds based on the filetype (you'll have to do a [`:syntax enable`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3asyntax-enable) before, maybe in your `.vimrc`).

I often end up setting `foldmethod` to [`marker`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-marker) and create the markers by myself.

If you want to keep your global setting of `fdm=manual`, you could specify a [`modeline`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) in those files that use different settings.

Answer (score 2):

Eckes is right - look at ':help foldmethod' to see what's possible. To give the z... commands a try, do ':set foldmethod=manual'.

Comment: Now, a short "manual folding tutorial": Open a file, say `gvim /etc/motd`. Select a range of lines (e.g. by pressing `v` and using the arrow keys. Then, `zf` will create a new fold, `zc` or `zr` or even just ` ` space will open/close it. -- You can also create a fold by using `zf{motion}`, e. g. `zf3j` will fold three lines starting from the current.

Comment: @PrestelNué, thanks; click EDIT and improve the answer.